# Trying to get hover effect to effect an a & a ul

Tags: html, css, hover, html-lists, anchor

I am new to html and css.

I am trying to add a hover effect to a small nav bar at the bottom of my page. The text has a border around it with text inside, and i want the hover effect to invert the design so the colour of the border becomes the background of the button and the text is the page background colour.

Because these are links to my other pages, i had to add css to the "li a" but now my hover effect wont effect the text until you hover over it.

Here is what i have:

```css
nav{

     position: fixed;
     bottom: 0%;
     left: 0%;
     right: 00%;
     display: block; 
     text-align: center;
}

ul{
    padding: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}

 li {
     font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
     font-size: 10px;
     font-weight: 100;
     line-height: 25px;
     text-align: center;
     width: 100px;
     border: solid #383838;
     border-width: 1px;
     color: #383838;
     list-style-type: none;
     float: left;
     margin: 5px;
 }

li a{
     color: #7f7f7f;
     text-decoration: none;
 }

li:hover{
    background: #7f7f7f;
    color: #000000;
}
li a:hover{
    background: #7f7f7f;
    color: #000000;
```

```html
 <body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">BLACK &amp; GOLD</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">BLACK &amp; WHITE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">WHITE &amp; GOLD</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">WHITE &amp; BLACK</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
```

Can anyone let me know what i need to do to fix this.

Thanks
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the hover selector from your `<a>` to your `<li>`.
This way, due to the cascading nature of CSS, your link will be styled differently if it's parent list item is hovered.

```css
nav {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0%;
 left: 0%;
 right: 00%;
 display: block; 
 text-align: center;
}

ul {
 padding: 0px;
 display: inline-block;
}

li {
 font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
 font-size: 10px;
 font-weight: 100;
 line-height: 25px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100px;
 border: solid #383838;
 border-width: 1px;
 color: #383838;
 list-style-type: none;
 float: left;
 margin: 5px;
 }

li a {
 color: #7f7f7f;
 text-decoration: none;
 }

li:hover {
background: #7f7f7f;
color: #000000;
}

li:hover a {
background: #7f7f7f;
color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">BLACK &amp; GOLD</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">BLACK &amp; WHITE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">WHITE &amp; GOLD</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">WHITE &amp; BLACK</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
```